# R Text Mining - Converting Term Document Matrix

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, term-document-matrix, rweka

I created a list of bigrams using:

```
BigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 2, max = 2))
tdm_a.bigram = TermDocumentMatrix(docs_a,
                                control = list(tokenize = BigramTokenizer))
```

I am trying to get a count of documents each bigram is appearing in. If I understand correctly Term Document Matrix will give how many times each bigram occurs within a document. But I just need 
'1'-present in a document and 
'0'-not there.

How do I convert Term Document Matrix into dataframe or matrix to be able to get such count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A TDM is a simple_triplet_matrix from the `slam` package. Which has some fucntions for common operations line row/colSums.

`slam::row_sums(tdm_a.bigram>=1)`

This should tell you how many documents contained each bigram.